# How do I know the server got closed with UDP using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, udp

I know UDP is not a connection oriented protocol but UDP is a requirement on what I have to do.

While I'm sending a bunch of packets from a client application to the server application, is there anyway to know if the server application got closed (eg. the user terminated the process)?

One way is to periodically ping the server (in a different thread from the one sending/receiving the data stream) and wait for a response. If the server doesn't acknowledge the ping, it may be down (although is not guaranteed, this is UDP after all).

But is there a better/simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way. The protocols I have implemented that use UDP as the transport use a request/response model. For example, [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol), does it this way (in general, of course):

Say you have 2 peers - A and B. If peer A sends a request to peer B, peer B should always send a response back. If peer A does not receive a response in a certain time, it resends the previous message. Peer A will keep resending the message until it gets a response from peer B OR until a specified expiry time (up to you what this is).  If that time has expired, you assume that peer B is down.

Answer (score 1):

When the server process is not running, your server OS *may* send an ICMP packet such as "destination port unreachable" back to the sender. Check with tcpdump or other packet sniffer. If so, then your client may be able to find out whether such a response was received.

Pinging (ICMP echo) the server won't be very useful because the OS will respond to ping whether or not your server process is running.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're right, UDP is an unreliable protocol. No handshake, no confirmation, no reliability.

Your best bet is to ping in a new thread, but do so in a UDP fashion (same endpoint implementation) but that's really not any more reliable than having the destination send a 'received ' UDP packet back. You're not going to do much better than that since its not an open connection that had a state, just either you sent a packet off and assume its arrived or you received data. There is also no guarantee about order of receipt, so you have to assume a ping was successful and didn't beat your actual payload there, or that you're not getting a success reply back from a different request.